# Err 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; Cannot create table

Tags: mariadb, innodb

sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `forum`
(
  `id` Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` Varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` Varchar() CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `register` Datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` Datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  `birth` Date NOT NULL,
  `about` Varchar(500),
  `sex` Bool,
  `group` Smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rank` Smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `avatar` Varbinary(2000) NOT NULL,
  `status` Tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`group`,`rank`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`group`,`rank`),
 UNIQUE `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
 COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci
; 
ALTER TABLE `Forum`.`users` ADD UNIQUE `login` (`login`)
;
```

Message log:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `forum`
(
  `id` Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log' at line 1
[Err] CREATE TABLE `forum`
(
  `id` Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` Varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` Varchar() CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `register` Datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` Datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  `birth` Date NOT NULL,
  `about` Varchar(500),
  `sex` Bool,
  `group` Smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rank` Smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `avatar` Varbinary(2000) NOT NULL,
  `status` Tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`group`,`rank`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`group`,`rank`),
 UNIQUE `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
 COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci
;
[Msg] Finished - Unsuccessfully
--------------------------------------------------
```

I'm looking at this and looking, seeking for solution on web and can't find what's wrong here.

Just can't execute this sql file, errors. UTF-8 coding.

SQL file dump created with Toad Data Modeler 6.1 Trial

Comment: Password varchar() - varchar needs a length,and primary key duplicated.

Comment: Apart from the errors mentioned already, your error message suggests that you are running multiple queries at once in a context where there is only one query at a time allowed (e.g. running your code using php), that might be an additional problem.

Comment: @P.Salmon  
Made change. Still the same error. As error says `http://wklej.to/0rCIT`

Comment: @Solarflare Running multiple queries on execution I have unchecked. And I run it by Navicat Premium

Comment: Your alter statement may not be correct either. If you really meant to alter forum then the .users may be incorrect. On the other hand if you have a db called forum with a table called users it may be correct...

Comment: I have @P.Salmon  I think problem is near line 1 as error says

Comment: Amended code compiles for me in mariadb with heidisql and also from command line. I wonder if navicat is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```sql
...
-- `password` Varchar() CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci NOT NULL,
`password` Varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci NOT NULL,
...
```

and

```sql
...
-- PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`group`,`rank`),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`group`,`rank`),
...
```

Comment: Made change. Still the same error. As error says ;`http://wklej.to/0rCIT`

Comment: @KrystianPolska: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db<>fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ba045a34a1cdcf3e57337d88f35ce239).

Comment: I doens't understand that. That's kinda insane. That I got this error on the same query and you doesn't : |

Comment: But the error message is pointing at `CREATE`, implying that what came _immediately_ before it is the problem.

Comment: @RickJames: The problem may be hidden characters at the end of the `CREATE` statement.

Comment: Then "near..." would point at the end.  Or did you mean at the end of the `CREATE` token?

Comment: There is no bad, hidden, character in what was pasted into this Question.

Comment: @RickJames: I just meant between `CREATE` and the first parenthesis `(`. Perhaps the sentence executed in Navicat is not exactly the one that was pasted in the question.

Comment: No, the "near" clause is very likely to be more precise than that.  If it is a bad character, it will be touching "CREATE".  More likely, the token immediately before "CREATE" got the query off to a bad start.

Comment: mysql> `SELECT CREATE TABLE blah ();`
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE blah ()' at line 1